# debugging stopped at React-Redux Connect periodically

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, subscription

I have been using React-Redux for a while but I always have a question while debugging the "connect" which interact between component and store, for example

```
ln    export default connect((state) => {
112     return {
113       isUserAdmin: isUserAdmin(state)
114     };
115   })(MainPage);

      isUserAdmin(state) {
222       // perform a heavy task...
      }
```

if I put a breakpoint at **line 113**, even if I didn't make any change in my component, I found that it's being triggered periodically every 1 seconds, as well as my function **isUserAdmin(state) is being executed again and again and never stopped**, is that something designed by react-redux?

I also found in my call stack there is some **Subscription** which triggered the connect(mapStateToProps), does it mean behind the scene react-redux is using some kind of **subscription or promise** to perform a polling to maintain the state?

BTW, if my **isUserAdmin** is doing a heavy job or I pass additional mapStateToProps through executing additional methods, would that impact a lot in my application performance since it seems running infinitely behind the scene?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> even if I didn't make any change in my component, I found that it's being triggered periodically every 1 seconds.

- It has no business with the changes (local component state updates) you do in your component (Unless you are doing any store updates by dispatching `actions`). It only listen to `store` updates.
- First time it triggers with the default `redux` `store` state upon application loading. The subsequent triggers depends on the store updates you are doing in your application/components by dispatching `actions`.

> does it mean behind the scene react-redux is using some kind of subscription or promise to perform a polling to maintain the state?

- Yes. It subscribes to store updates.
  Things are well explained [here](https://medium.com/@fknussel/redux-3cb5aac94a66).

> if my isUserAdmin is doing a heavy job or I pass additional mapStateToProps through executing additional methods, would that impact a lot in my application performance.

- **React** will come as a **savior** for you here. UI/Component won't re-render if the state/reference is not changed.

I would recommend you to move `isUserAdmin` logic to react component and use `useMemo()` hook to get performance optimization for intense calculations. For your [reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo).

Comment: Thank you! Yeah looks like there is a dispatch out of my current component, that `somehow` triggers the dispatch of my component...
Regarding my third question (if my isUserAdmin is doing a heavy job), yes my state or my UI/component did not change, my concern is the method `isUserAdmin` still will be executing right? Suppose it would take 2 second for executing the `isUserAdmin`, does that mean each time an outside dispatch will trigger the `isUserAdmin` that would take 2 second to complete?

Comment: Yes. It would execute everytime and takes those 2 seconds. Move the `isUserAdmin` to component and wrap it with `useMemo()` as suggested in answer or use libraries like [memoize-one](https://github.com/alexreardon/memoize-one) for performance optimization. It skips the execution if the input arguments are same in subsequent calls and save those 2 seconds for you in both the cases (`useMemo()`/`memoize-one`).